Stochastic Order Symbols -Unusual Notation
The professor provided us with the following definition of big-oh-P-one, which seems a bit unusual compared to other sources I've found. The definition is:
Let $Z_n$ and $a_n$, $n = 1, 2, \ldots$ be sequences of random variables and constants, respectively. The notation $Z_n = O_p(1)$ (``big oh-P-one'') means that $Z_n$ is bounded in probability. Precisely, for any $\epsilon > 0$, there is a constant $M_\epsilon < \infty$ such that
\begin{equation}
\limsup_{n \to \infty} P(|Z_n| > M_\epsilon) \leq \epsilon.
\end{equation}
Q1: Why is it necessary to use the supremum in this definition?
Q2: The intuition seems to be that the probability of $Z_n$ exceeding a large constant $M$ becomes small for sufficiently large $n$. Is this interpretation correct? Why is this concept particularly useful in econometrics?


The notation is standard.  See, e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_inferior_and_limit_superior.  2. Consider asking on the SE Econ site.


@whuber Thank you for your response! Could you recommend a rigorous yet accessible book that builds a strong foundation in econometric theory? The well-known texts, such as Wooldridge or Greene, provide limited coverage of asymptotic theory. For instance, concepts like convergence in quadratic mean are not thoroughly addressed in these books.

Personally I cannot make such a recommendation, but check out what others on this site have said.
